# Why can I not mix Scala code with HTML here in Play Framework 2 views?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I made a sample which is supposed to read a JSON file and present its data as HTML in a regular view in Play Framework 2.2.

The view looks like this:

```
@(json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue)

@import play.api.libs.json._

@main("JSON Read") {

    <h1>JSON Read</h1>

    <p>This sample reads a JSON file containing some book categories and a few books inside these categories.</p>
    <!-- THIS WORKS -->
    <p>This link demonstrates a route with parameter: <a href="@routes.JsonSamples.bookdetails("12345678")">Link to book 12345678</a></p>

    @json.as[List[JsObject]].map { section =>
        <table>
            <caption>
                <h2>@{(section \ "title").as[String]}</h2>
                <p>@{(section \ "description").as[String]}</p>
            </caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Book Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        @{(section \ "entries").as[List[JsObject]].map { entry =>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!-- By the way... I can't even use @* *@ comments here. Why? -->

                        <!-- I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT INTO HREF, NOTHING WORKS, SEE BELOW -->
                        <a href="#">
                            {(entry \ "title").as[String]}
                        </a>

                        <!-- THIS WORKS -->
                        (ID: {(entry \ "id").as[String]})
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>{(entry \ "description").as[String]}</p>
                        <p>Order link: {(entry \ "link").as[String]}</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        }}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }

}
```

Somewhere in the middle you can see I try to insert a generated link for each book, but I simply can't get anything printed inside the `href=""` attribute of the `<a>` tag. I tried:

```
Attempt 1:
<a href="@routes.JsonSamples.bookdetails((entry \ "id").as[String])">
...Compilation error: unclosed multi-line string literal

Attempt 2:
<a href="@(routes.JsonSamples.bookdetails((entry \ "id").as[String]))">
...Compilation error: in XML literal: whitespace expected

Attempt 3:
<a href="@{routes.JsonSamples.bookdetails((entry \ "id").as[String])}">
...Compilation error: in XML literal: whitespace expected

Attempt 4:
<a href="{routes.JsonSamples.bookdetails((entry \ "id").as[String])}">
...Compilation error: in XML literal: whitespace expected
```

Sometimes you can simply use `@` sign to display data.

Sometimes you have to use `@` *and* wrap code with `{}` (i.e. `@{…}`).

Sometimes `@` is not even allowed and you must only use `{}`.

And sometimes none of these methods work.

It's seems obvious that it must have to do with the fact if the code is inside another code block or not. But (in probably most cases) everything is wrapped into `@main {…}` anyway and it works, but the more code blocks you wrap the more difficult it seems to get values displayed.

So, the main specific question is: How can I display the link/route above where it currently only says `href="#"`?

And the more general question is: Is there a clear understandable way how to mix code with HTML?

The JSON file: https://github.com/Manc/play-samples/blob/json/data/books.json

The controller: https://github.com/Manc/play-samples/blob/json/app/controllers/JsonSamples.scala

The view: https://github.com/Manc/play-samples/blob/json/app/views/jsonsamples/read.scala.html

I also noted that even `@* *@` comment blocks are not allowed everywhere in a view.

I come from PHP and it's always very clear what's PHP code and what isn't. Even, e.g. Laravel's (a PHP framework) template engine *Blade* uses a similar approach, where you can mix in code with an `@` sign or `{{ … }}` to print a value of a variable/function/method or `{{{ … }}}` to do the same but HTML-safe escaped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a quick fix

```
@for(entry <- (section \ "entries").as[List[JsObject]]) {
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="@routes.JsonSamples.bookdetails((entry \ "id").as[String])">
        @{(entry \ "title").as[String]}
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>@{(entry \ "description").as[String]}</p>
      <p>Order link: @{(entry \ "link").as[String]}</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

The problem with your code is the use of `@{...}`. The thing is, all inside that block is treated as scala code. That is why `@**@` comments do not work, they are not valid scala syntax. Scala has xml literals which allow for the html tags inside.

Which means we need to get out of the scala syntax for the inside of the loop. The problem is, that I couldn't find a way to do this and keep the map syntax. Because there are parentheses around `section \ "entries"` in `@(section \ "entries").as[List[JsObject]].map { entry =>`, the template engine considers only that part as scala code. To work around that you can use the alternative syntax with `for`.

So use `@` for simple expressions. Use `@{...}` for not so simple expressions, but keep in mind that everything inside the block is scala code (so no further `@`). The places where you cannot use the `@` are within scala code.

This may lead to problems when the simple expression is not enough and you need to do a `map` or something, but there is always the `defining` helper and you shouldn't do too complex things in a template anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your excellent explanation. It works perfectly fine the way you changed the code. I hope I'll get used to this syntax. :)